# What does "a lagoon by la mere" mean

Tags: meaning, lyrics

What does this verse from *Mike Oldfield*'s *Foreign Affair* song mean?

> a lagoon by la mere

Comment: "La mer" - the sea (French)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a look at the verse as a whole....

> Foreign affair.
>
> Take a trip in the air
>
> To a tropical beach,
>
> An island to reach.
>
> A new territory
>
> For an intimate story,
>
> **A lagoon by la mere**.
>
> It's a foreign affair.

... I would imagine that '*la mere*' is an anglicization of the french '*la mer*', which quite literally means '*the sea*'.

A lagoon is a shallow body of water separated from a larger body of water, quite often from the sea, therefore 'a lagoon by la mere' is a shallow lake, cut off from the ocean, which is quite in keeping with the tropical island setting of the song.

Comment: Also "la mere" rhymes with "affair".  "By the beach" would have required a different word to end the couplet.